# iOS: background play from the browser?

Tags: ios, html

Some iOS apps like Pandora continue playing audio after the app screen has been exited, and even after the device has been locked.

Is it possible to keep audio playing in this way from a browser tab?  In other words, can I code an HTML5 page that plays audio and continues playing even after the iPhone is locked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, audio playing in a mobile Safari tab will continuously play even when multi-tasking or locking your screen. However, if you save the bookmark to the home screen, open, play audio, and then hop out to multi-task, the audio fades out.

Answer (score -1):

Not possible... the browser displaying your page controls what happens when it is deactivated (sent to the background).  HTML5 won't touch the behavior of the underlying browser as it relates to system events, so the only way to control background activity in iOS is to write a native app.

Comment: In iOS 5, and iOS 4 (IIRC), using Safari with HTML 5 <audio> allows audio to continue playing in the background if you switch away from Safari. What does not work is that if you bookmark the app to the homescreen this ability breaks. There's also an issue with any kind of playlist controls in iOS 5, where advancement won't happen. Google Music currently has this problem and there is no existing solution that I am aware of.